# DTMF decode using python

Tags: python, python-2.7, raspberry-pi3, at-command

I am trying to decode DTMF codes received to `SIM-800` module using a python script.

My code :

```
import serial,time

serialport = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyS0", 115200,timeout=1)

while True:
    command = serialport.read(10)
    ring = "RING"
    ring_command = command.decode('utf-8')
    ring_command = ring_command.strip()

    if ring_command == ring:

        serialport.write("ATA"+"\r")
        print serialport.read(20)

        serialport.write("AT+DDET=1"+"\r\n")  # enable DTMF 
        time.sleep(2)

        while True:
            dtmf = serialport.read(20)

            if dtmf != "":
                dtmf_new = dtmf.strip('+DTMF:')
                print dtmf_new
                time.sleep(1)
            else:
                print "There were notthing"
```

But still I am getting output as : `+DTMF: B`.
To decode `RING` command I have used given instructions in [raspberry-exchange](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/102239/response-to-a-incoming-call-using-python-script).
Here also I have tried `decode('utf-8')` before `strip()`, but still same answer.

DTMF code is sent by another `SIM-800` and Raspberry-pi.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you want to accomplish with `dtmf_new = dtmf.strip('+DTMF:')` and how looks the value of `dtmf` after `.read(...`. Last, what do you expect to be in `dtmf_new`?

Comment: I added `dtmf_new` just to be more clear. `dtmf -> +DTMF: A`, I expect `dtmf_new = A`

Comment: I think , you don't have to config the modem **after** receiving a **`'RING'`**. Move both `.write("ATA"+"\r")` and `.write("AT+DDET=1"+"\r\n")` outside of the `while True:` and send it before and only **once**.

Comment: @stovfl so how am I supposed to answer the call without using `ATA`?

Comment: You are right, `"ATA"` have to be there, but why do you use only '\r'? What do you want to accomplish with `"AT+DDET=1"`?

Comment: @stovfl As I read somewhere, we need to initialize modem to accept `DTMF` over gsm call. Thats why `AT+DDET=1` is used.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199524/discussion-between-stovfl-and-sachith).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my issue with help from @stovfl and some colleagues in my office.

I have just changed how I strip the result code receive from DTMF.

```
import serial,time

serialport = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyS0", 115200,timeout=1)

while True:
    command = serialport.read(10)
    print(command)
    ring = "RING"
    ring_command = command.decode('utf-8')       # Incoming call
    ring_command = ring_command.strip()          # Decoding incoming RING message
    print("Ring decoded : "+ ring_command)

    if ring_command == ring:
        serialport.write("ATA"+"\r")
        print serialport.read(10)

        serialport.write("AT+DDET=1"+"\r\n")     # enable DTMF
        print serialport.read(10)

        while True:
            dtmf = serialport.read(20)

            if len(dtmf) > 8:
                print dtmf[9]             # Just print the code we sent, Original -> `+DTMF: C`
                time.sleep(1)
            else:
                print "DTMF is less than 8 char"
                time.sleep(1)
```

I above code, I tried to remove `+DTMF:` from my string, here I just get `[9]` th element from the receiving string.

This is 100% working code now, tested many times.